# SQL Server Management Studio crashes when attaching an mdf file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, permissions, ssms

After the Windows 10 November update 1511, 10586 I cannot attach my databases with SSMS. It would just say that it has stopped working as shown below

[image: SSMS has stopped working]

I checked the error log and so far this is what I've got

> 2016-01-19 02:35:46.19 spid51      Attempting to load library 'xprepl.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
>   2016-01-19 02:35:46.21 spid51      Using 'xprepl.dll' version '2014.120.2000' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_repl_encrypt'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
>   2016-01-19 02:35:49.34 spid10s     .NET Framework runtime has been stopped.
>   2016-01-19 02:35:49.47 spid10s     SQL Server is terminating in response to a 'stop' request from Service Control Manager. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
>   2016-01-19 02:35:49.47 spid10s     SQL Trace was stopped due to server shutdown. Trace ID = '1'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.

What could be the problem? I've tried googling if this was a common issue but unfortunately there were no similar problems.

I have tried repairing SSMS through the installer.

**Update error log**

> 2016-01-19 12:16:48.69 spid52      Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>   2016-01-19 12:16:48.69 spid52      FCB::Open failed: Could not open file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\GroundCommander.mdf for file number 0.  OS error: 5(Access is denied.).
>   2016-01-19 12:16:49.26 spid52      Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>   2016-01-19 12:16:49.26 spid52      FCB::Open failed: Could not open file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\GroundCommander.mdf for file number 0.  OS error: 5(Access is denied.).
>   2016-01-19 12:16:49.48 spid52      Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>   2016-01-19 12:16:49.48 spid52      FCB::Open failed: Could not open file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\GroundCommander.mdf for file number 0.  OS error: 5(Access is denied.).
>   2016-01-19 12:16:49.61 spid52      Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>   2016-01-19 12:16:49.61 spid52      FCB::Open failed: Could not open file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\GroundCommander.mdf for file number 0.  OS error: 5(Access is denied.).
>   2016-01-19 12:16:49.83 spid52      Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>   2016-01-19 12:16:49.83 spid52      FCB::Open failed: Could not open file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\GroundCommander.mdf for file number 0.  OS error: 5(Access is denied.).
>   2016-01-19 12:16:49.98 spid52      Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>   2016-01-19 12:16:49.98 spid52      FCB::Open failed: Could not open file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\GroundCommander.mdf for file number 0.  OS error: 5(Access is denied.).
>   2016-01-19 12:16:50.21 spid52      Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>   2016-01-19 12:16:50.21 spid52      FCB::Open failed: Could not open file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\GroundCommander.mdf for file number 0.  OS error: 5(Access is denied.).
>   2016-01-19 12:16:50.36 spid52      Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>   2016-01-19 12:16:50.36 spid52      FCB::Open failed: Could not open file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\GroundCommander.mdf for file number 0.  OS error: 5(Access is denied.).
>   2016-01-19 12:16:50.57 spid52      Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>   2016-01-19 12:16:50.57 spid52      FCB::Open failed: Could not open file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\GroundCommander.mdf for file number 0.  OS error: 5(Access is denied.).
>   2016-01-19 12:16:50.75 spid52      Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>   2016-01-19 12:16:50.75 spid52      FCB::Open failed: Could not open file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\GroundCommander.mdf for file number 0.  OS error: 5(Access is denied.).
>   2016-01-19 12:16:50.91 spid52      Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>   2016-01-19 12:16:50.91 spid52      FCB::Open failed: Could not open file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\GroundCommander.mdf for file number 0.  OS error: 5(Access is denied.).
>   2016-01-19 12:16:55.58 spid54      Attempting to load library 'xpstar.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
>   2016-01-19 12:16:55.60 spid54      Using 'xpstar.dll' version '2014.120.2000' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_instance_regread'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.

Comment: This looks like an OS permission issue (*"OS error: 5(Access is denied.)"*) Does the account that SQL Server runs have permissions to the folder?

Comment: If the sql server is local then try login to sql server using windows authentication as local admins or domain admins. Make sure local admins or domain admins is added as database administrator role in sql server. Ms sql server by default can login using windows authenticity or sql authenticity. Then try using sql console again as local (pc) or domain admins.

Comment: I had the same problem. Runing SSMS as Administrator fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@J.P Masangcay`, I have gone through your Error log and find out two things which is as follows :

```
1) Error: 17204
2) OS error: 5(Access is denied)
```

I would like to say that as `@ypercubeᵀᴹ` already comments it's related to os like `OS permission issue`.
So, as per above errors definitely we can say that it's `Windows Service Accounts` based errors.

> The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service account and members of the local
>   Windows Administrators group.

AS per MSDN BOL  [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189128.aspx) When you are detaching or attaching a database, the Database Engine tries to impersonate the Windows account of the connection performing the operation to guarantee that the account has permission to access the database and log files.

Depending on the type of operation [opening databases during server startup, database attach, restore, etc] the user account that is used for impersonation and accessing the database file will vary. `For Ref` [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2015754) and [Here](http://www.sqlserverf1.com/tag/error-17204-severity-16-state-1/).

Hope it will help out to you.